# How can I implement the server side pagination of mui-datatable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

How can I implement the server side pagination of mui-datatable?

Problems:

- I can't seem to retrieve whatever value was selected by the user in the `rowsPerPage options`. If the user clicks `15`, then these `rowsPerPage` inside the `useEffect` should be updated as well:

  ```
  const getUsers = async () => {
     const usersRef = collection(db, "users");
     const q = query(
       usersRef,
       orderBy("firstName", "asc"),
       limit(rowsPerPage)
     );
     const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
     const arr = [];
     querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       arr.push({
         ...doc.data()
       });
     });
     if (isMounted) {
       setUsers(arr);
       setCount(arr.length);
       loading(true);
     }
   };
  ```
- How does the server side pagination and filter works for mui-datatable?

Recreated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-datatable-server-side-pagination-filtering-and-sorting-y8pyp7?file=/src/App.js:611-1091

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty obvious that in the sandbox in your code you have state

```
const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(10);
```

and the IDE underlines `setRowsPerPage` showing you that it's never used, so even if the user changes the value the state is not updated.

[The docs](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables) show there's `onChangeRowsPerPage` which you can pass a callback to in order to update the state and then use the state's value to send to the backend

Answer (score 0):

I found examples from (it's from official examples):
[click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/gregnb/mui-datatables?file=/src/index.js)

it has good example how to handle pagination

the logic is:

you should have pageSize state that handle pageSize

onPageSize change update pageSize state

Comment: hello, I'm quite confused on how to implement how the page changes for the next pages? https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-datatable-server-side-pagination-filtering-and-sorting-y8pyp7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i will update my answer with logic explanation